# Adding http headers to window.location.href in Angular app

Tags: angularjs, http, oauth-2.0, http-headers, window.location

I have a angular app that I needed to redirect outside to a non angular html page, so I thought I could just use the `$window.location.href`to redirect the angular app to my external site. This actually works fine, however, I have a nodejs/express backend that checks for auth token before serving up any content(even static content).

This requires a auth token to be sent in the header of the http request.  Now the question:

Can/How do you add an auth token to the request that is made by changing the `$window.location.href` before it is sent off?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When you use `$window.location.href` the browser is making the HTTP request and not your JavaScript code.  Therefore, you cannot add a custom header like `Authorization` with your token value.

You could add a cookie via JavaScript and put your auth token there.  The cookies will automatically be sent from the browser.  However, you will want to review the security implications of using a cookie vs. a header.  Since both are accessible via JavaScript, there is no additional attack vector there. Unless you remove the cookie after the new page loads, there may be a CSRF exploit available.

Comment: great answer, I wonder if angular-cookies would work for this.  Anyways thanks for the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

**This answer is NOT a safe way, as the token is exposed in the URL, which is logged in browser history, access logs, etc. Use a domain cookie instead. I'll leave the answer as it can be an easy way to debug in your local setup.**

I am using JWT as authentication on a Laravel PHP backend, and it works by putting `?token=...` in the URL. For example, when using AngularJS with satellizer plug-in, I add `?token=' + $auth.getToken()` to the URL.

Comment: well embedding token as URL parameter is the last thing that i would like to do.

Comment: Even in SSL a sniffer could read the URL of the request so it is WORST way to pass a token to a request. If you're using SSL you should put the token in headers or in body.

Comment: "in SSL a sniffer could read the URL of the request" 
This is not true, only the hostname/ip can be detected, not the url.

Comment: Two vulnerabilities of doing this are: (1) The token is in the IIS logs (2) Drive by hacking, e.g. someone looks at your browser url or grabs it from your browser history while you make a cup of coffee

Comment: This solution must be avoided for security reason as well explained by @tony