# Add headers to a link in angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, http-headers

I have an angular app that I need to redirect outside to a server side html page, so I thought I could just use a standard `<a>` tag with `target='_self'` to redirect the angular app to my server side page. This actually works fine, however, I have a rails backend that checks for auth token before serving up any content.

This requires a auth token to be sent in the header of the http request which I am setting in a cookie, and angular grabs automatically with the `$http` service for ajax requests, but I can't seem to get the same thing to happen on a standard link.

Can/How do you add an auth token to a normal link before it is sent off?

Answer (score 2):

When the browser is making the HTTP request and not your JavaScript code, you cannot add a custom header with your token value.  See [Adding http headers to window.location.href in Angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130004/adding-http-headers-to-window-location-href-in-angular-app/26373493) for a similar question.

However, if this value is already being sourced from a cookie, can your backend just read that cookie value (or use some filter in the http request chain to transfer the cookie to a header)?