# Add Header to window.location.pathname

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication, jwt

I am setting up authentication for an app. After I make a post request to login, a JSON Web Token is sent in response. I am able to attach this to the header via Ajax. The problem is when using window.location.pathname to redirect after login, since it is not an Ajax request it does not have the token attached to the header. How do I get around this?

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'x-access-token': window.localStorage.jwt
  }
});

var Auth = {
  signup: function () {
    console.log('signuppp');
    var userSignup = {
      username: $('#usernameSignup').val(),
      password: $('#passwordSignup').val()
    };
    console.log(userSignup)
    return $.post('/api/users/register', userSignup, function (resp) {
      console.log('resp: ',resp);
      window.localStorage.setItem('jwt', resp.token);
      
      //does not have x-access-token header
      window.location.pathname = '/';
    })
  },
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short answer is: you cannot set HTTP headers using `window.location`.

[Adding http headers to window.location.href in Angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130004/adding-http-headers-to-window-location-href-in-angular-app?answertab=active#tab-top)