# How to create an Ajax GET that behaves like window.location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got a csv that I've been able to retreive using
`window.location = "/path/to/mydata"`, which I understand creates a GET request to that location. Now I'd like to add header params, so I do something like this...

```
$.ajax(
    url:"/path/to/mydata",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {"my-header": "..."})
.done((data){
    // "data" is now a string of my csv data
    console.log(data)
});
```

When I simply do `window.location` chrome somehow detects that I got a CSV file back and saves the contents locally to My Downloads. I'm not sure how to do that with the ajax `done` callback function, or if there is an ajax parameter that I could use that does it automatically.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966526/add-header-to-window-location-pathname

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Sounds like you really want to [download a file with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax) so you can set a header.