# how to redirect User to another web-page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My RestAPI server redirects a user request to another webpage (for example google.com) how can I redirect my fron-end to that page, I mean I have a button, when I press on it sends an axios request to my server. my server redirects it to another web page, and I want to show to my client that web-page

I have made an axios

```
 const url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://147.13.121.244:4001/redirect"
const client = axios.create({
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic a3p0ZXN5547asdhMnFUdVZN',

  }
});

let result = await client.get(url, {}).then((response) => {
  return response
}).catch((error) => {
  return error
})
```

Comment: just get the url from the server, then window.location = newUrl

Comment: is the page part of your app or on another host?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location` to redirect the current page to the URL you receive from the server or `window.open` to open that page in another tab.

For example:

```
const redirectURL = // result.redirect
// Redirect
window.location = redirectURL;
// New Window
window.open(redirectURL, "_blank");
```

You'll have to examine the `result` object to figure out how exactly to get the redirect URL, but once you have it, these will work.

Comment: the thing is I need to set Basic Auth before redirection if I will make window.location = result.url; it does not set header I guess

Comment: is the redirect location part of your app or on another host?

Comment: Redirect will execute a new http request and your headers will be lost.

Comment: @HastaTamang I have a url ("http://google.com") I want to move my client to that url and I need my user to have authorization in Header, how can I solve that

Comment: @HenryWoody another

Comment: It does not seem possible to set HTTP headers when redirecting client-side. Examples: [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236874/setting-custom-request-header-on-a-page-redirect), [b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966526/add-header-to-window-location-pathname), [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966526/add-header-to-window-location-pathname), [d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835783/adding-http-request-header-to-a-a-href-link)

Comment: Use `query string` or `session`

Comment: @HastaTamang, I need to authorize in another web-page not mine, is it possible to set session in my server, redirect to another web-page and authorize there with session?

Comment: Also how do you have access authorization headers to another host from your site? (seems like a possible security hazard)

Comment: @HenryWoody, yeah I know, the thing is, this another page is a bank and I am making a platform where people can make loan orders, In the API which the bank gave us, there is a method which  returns a URL if every credential is right, so they want us to redirect a client to the url and the client should be authorized (in client's header should be basic auth) and Idk how to do that, how to redirect with header

Comment: You should maybe look into the [OAuth2 protocol](https://oauth.net/2/). I don't think your application should receive someone else's bank credentials even if you just pass them along to the bank site. If you're developing for the bank and working with them, then maybe you can just use the query string and then let the bank take information from the query string (but the user would still need to log into the bank site separately)